# Why does reading a "line" from data = response.read() give an integer?

Tags: python, decode, urllib

I have some Python function that takes a url to a text file and downloads it ('url' will always be a text file). I want to be able to decode that text file line by line, and add each line as a string to a list of strings.

```
    def download_index(self, url):
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        data = response.read()
        listOfStrings = []
        for line in data:
            print(line)
            listOfStrings.append(line)
```

When I run this, 'line' is an integer.
If instead I print 'data', it prints the whole text file, un-decoded.

If I decode 'data', I can't process it line by line because I've removed the code telling it where the line breaks are. EDIT: I must have misunderstood how decoding works. I was under this impression because when I tried to decode 'data' and then process it line by line, each 'line' was a single character in one large decoded string

It seems like the only way to do this would be to go through 'data' line by line, decode each line, and then add them to the list. But I can't do that because like I said, if I try to write something like `for line in data` the compiler tells me that `line` is an integer. And indeed, if I try to add `print(line)`, I get random integers

Comment: Iterating over a bytestring gives individual bytes (as ints), not lines.

Comment: "If I decode 'data', I can't process it line by line because I've removed the code telling it where the line breaks are." - that is not how decoding works. Decoding does not remove line break information.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica got it, that makes sense. any idea how I can get the actual decoded lines from the text file separated into a list?

Comment: Try iterating over `response`, not `data`. Then you'll be iterating over the file itself, not the contents of it, right? Let me know if this works so I can submit it as an answer.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I must have misunderstood what decode does then. I added an edit explaining why I assumed that it worked that way. I'm still unsure of where to go from here

Comment: @micpap25 that's not working either, and I'm not really sure what it's actually doing. I tried iterating through response and I added a print statement to see what a 'line' of response looks like, but it never even executed

Comment: Iterating over a text string gives individual characters (as strings), not lines. (Strictly speaking, it gives individual Unicode code points, while the user-facing notion of "character" more closely corresponds to grapheme clusters.)

Comment: For micpap25's suggestion, remove the `response.read()` call first.

Comment: @micpap25 it worked once I removed `response.read()` as per Monica's suggestion. Thank you very much, please feel free to add as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I run this, 'line' is an integer.

When you iterate over a file-like object, you get lines.

When you iterate over a `bytes` object, you get individual byte values. Which are integers (ranging from 0-255 inclusive).

(The name you use for the loop variable is *not relevant* to the behaviour.)

> EDIT: I must have misunderstood how decoding works. I was under this impression because when I tried to decode 'data' and then process it line by line, each 'line' was a single character in one large decoded string

Same thing. When you iterate over a `str`, you get individual Unicode code points (which under normal circumstances will appear to you to be "characters").

> It seems like the only way to do this would be to go through 'data' line by line, decode each line, and then add them to the list.

You can, in fact, do this, and it's a reasonable approach. The trick is to **not** `.read()` the whole `response` in advance, and instead iterate *directly over the `response`*:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
listOfStrings = []
for line in response:
    # Of course, you need to know and use the actual encoding;
    # this is a guess on my part.
    listOfStrings.append(line.decode('utf-8'))
```

You can also use a list comprehension here:

```
listOfStrings = [line.decode('utf-8') for line in urllib.request.urlopen(url)]
```

Comment: Perfect. In order to fully understand this I'm going to have to look up what a 'response' is content-wise, and what the 'read' method actually does. Excellent explanation, thank you for your time

Comment: It provides the same interface as a file.

Comment: Note that decoding individual lines this way only works because of properties specific to UTF-8 (specifically, how it encodes line breaks). For general encoding handling, you would want to do something like wrap the response object in an `io.TextIOWrapper` with the encoding set, and iterate over the wrapper.

Comment: True, "lines" of a stream of bytes might not be split up the way you want, depending on the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can restructure the code like this:

```
def download_index(self, url):
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        listOfStrings = []
        for line in response:
            print(line)
            listOfStrings.append(line)
```

There's a bit of syntactic sugar on Python's part that allows you to iterate over a file directly to get each line of text from it. By iterating over `data`, you were going through each character of a bytestring and getting individual characters. This code iterates directly over `response` and gets all the lines you need.